# Commas using adverbs and clauses

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

Where should my commas be placed in the sentence below for proper punctuation?

When the market place is expensive meaning higher prices the result is a low demand, since the same amount of money can buy someone less of a particular good or service, additionally even if consumer wants to buy, they might not have the wealth to buy at high prices.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your text consists of two sentences run together. You should split it before 'Additionally'.
Other than that, you need additional commas before and after the parenthetical phrase 'meaning higher prices' and another one after 'Additionally'.

By the way, 'goods' can't be turned into the singular 'good'. Rather say 'commodity'.